# Git/Github based tool for exploring a Network for Forks?

Tags: git, github

Say I find a project [like this](https://github.com/andyforever/json-editor/network) which has hundreds of forks. If I want to look at each forks commit messages It's a lot of work scrolling.

In some cases there are just too many forks so you can't see anything at all.

Anyone know of a better tool to do with this?

[image]